# Returning http response from a angular 2 service

Tags: angularjs, http

I have the following code for my service

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Response} from "angular2/http";
import {PRIVATE_SERVERS} from "../mock/private_servers_list";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
/*import {PRIVATE_SERVERS} from "../mock/private_servers_list";*/

@Injectable()
export class PrivateServerService {
    http= null;
    PRIVATE_SERVERS = null;

    constructor(http:Http){
        this.http = http;
    }

    logError(err){
        console.log("some error");
    }

    getPrivateServers(){
        this.http.get('http://private-server.eviry.com/get_private_servers')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this.PRIVATE_SERVERS = data, //printing data here gives me the correct value
                err => this.logError(err),
                () => console.log('Private Server fetching complete')
            );

        console.log(this.PRIVATE_SERVERS);
        return this.PRIVATE_SERVERS;

    }
}
```

I have injected this service in to a component called private-server.component. Basically, in this service I am trying to get a list of private servers using the url `http://private-server.eviry.com/get_private_servers`

I access this url in `getPrivateServers()` function. When I print the response within the subscribe method, I can see the data fetched correctly.

However, when I try to `console.log(this.PRIVATE_SERVERS)`, it prints null. Is this the correct way to use the angular service or is there a way to make it wait for the response?

Answer (score 0):

The assignment happens in an asynchronous callback. If you want to use its value outside that callback, you need to wait for it to complete.

Comment: ok, how can I do that? Or is there a way to do it in a synchronous manner? Is there a better architecture than this to use it asynchronously?

Comment: @user3288346 You pretty much have to use another asynchronous callback, I think. Alternatively, since this is Angular, only kick off the http request the first time the function's called, return whatever value you've got at the moment, and depend on Angular's dirty checking to update things when the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Event Emitter](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) to react asynchronous to the response. 
Here is an good introduction to [Observables](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-new-http-module-1278499db2a0#.l471016gt) in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

**PrivateServerService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import { Response } from "angular2/http";
import { PRIVATE_SERVERS } from "../mock/private_servers_list";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
/*import {PRIVATE_SERVERS} from "../mock/private_servers_list";*/

@Injectable()
export class PrivateServerService {
    PRIVATE_SERVERS = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.setPrivateServerMocksData();
    }

    logError(err) {
        console.log("some error");
    }

    getPrivateServers() {
        return this.http.get('http://private-server.eviry.com/get_private_servers')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    setPrivateServerMocksData() {
        this.getPrivateServers()
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.PRIVATE_SERVERS = data
                console.log(this.PRIVATE_SERVERS);
            },
            (err) => {
                this.logError(err)
            });
    }

}
```

**YourComponent.ts**

```
 getPrivateServerInfo() {
                this.privateServerService.getPrivateServers()
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        //you have your data here to work with
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        this.logError(err)
                    });
            }
```